# How to fill the Nan value based on the other table in Python?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a table with lots of Nan values in 'Rating':

**Category   Rating**  
A           3.4   
C           Nan   
B           4.0   
A           Nan   
A           3.5   
B           Nan 
C           4.0   
A           Nan   
...          ...

Then I  calculate the mean value of each category in Python and create another table:

**Category    Mean_rating**
A              4.3
B              3.9
C              3.2

How to fill this mean value into the first table based on the 'Category'?

Answer (score 1):

We can do `transform` create the `mean` and `fillna`

```
df.Rating.fillna(df.groupby('Category').Rating.transform('mean'),inplace=True)
df
  Category  Rating
0        A    3.40
1        C    4.00
2        B    4.00
3        A    3.45
4        A    3.50
5        B    4.00
6        C    4.00
7        A    3.45
```

Comment: Does `combine_first` not work in this case? I tried it out but couldn't get it to work.